# After update, Windows 8.1 has an open cmd box when restarted and also a message, is it infected?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, cmd.exe

my Windows 8.1 HP laptop recently updated automatically and now when it is restarted a cmd line box is on the desktop, followed shortly by a message saying;
"Windows cannot find c:\program files(x86)\search extensions\client.exe"
This never happened before, is it something I need to fix?
After update, Windows 8.1 has an open cmd box when restarted and also a message, is it infected?

Comment: if you don't want this ncon't find tab then go and watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lf91e4xG6Wo

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIenM5ymLUE

Comment: See video tutorial: [Remove Client.exe Error Message – Windows cannot find c:\program files(x86)\search Extensions\client](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lf91e4xG6Wo)

Answer (score 1):

You installed a malicious program and it's broken. The executable may have been removed by your antivirus. It's not a virus. It's a program that tries hard to be as malicious as it gets without being illegal. These programs are usually bundled with legitimate software by borderline malicious download sites like Softonic, CNet, and many many others.

https://herdprotect.com/client.exe-6b75d6a615b532e67c2e62ccff0443455a6d7c40.aspx

> Secureencoded
>
> This adware bundler is distributed through Adknowledge's advertising
>   supported software managers. The application Client.exe by
>   Secureencoded has been detected as adware by 3 anti-malware scanners. [...] Additionally, the file is typically installed by a number of programs including Rockettab by Rich River Media, LLC and “RocketTab” by “RocketTab”, both potentially unwanted software.
>
> [...]
>
> Common path: C:\Program Files\search extensions\client.exe

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/error-message-after-booting-computer-error-windows/d22d1f93-8c13-462b-a081-69a196bc04b2

Comment: Microsoft changed the criteria for treating this type of program as malware recently. The Malicious Software Removal Tool may have deleted this but missed its startup location. http://blogs.technet.com/b/mmpc/archive/2014/10/17/staying-in-control-of-your-browser-new-detection-changes.aspx